# What are 'batches' and 'steps' in TensorFlow Estimators and how do they differ from epochs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, training-data

I am attempting to use TensorFlow's Estimators. In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/#running_the_abalone_model) the following code is used to train and evaluate the network.

```
# Fit
nn.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=5000)

# Score accuracy
ev = nn.evaluate(x=test_set.data, y=test_set.target, steps=1)
loss_score = ev["loss"]
print("Loss: %s" % loss_score)
```

The whole training set is passed in, but we have `steps=5000`. Does this mean that only the first 5000 examples from the set are considered?

What does the `batch_size` parameter mean in this context, and how does it interact with `steps`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**batch_size** is the number of examples processed at once.  TF pushes all of those through one forward pass (in parallel) and follows with a back-propagation on the same set.  This is one *iteration*, or *step*.

The **steps** parameter tells TF to run 5000 of these iterations to train the model.

One **epoch** is treating each example in the training set exactly once.  For instance, if you have one million examples and a batch size of 200, then you need 5000 steps to one epoch: 200 * 5.000 = 1.000.000

Does that clear up the terminology?

Comment: That is useful info, thanks! Follow-up questions: I didn't realise it pushed many training examples through at once, how do the error calculations work in this case? Are all the weight changes added up and averaged? Does each batch consist of random training examples from the training set?

Comment: Yes, they're averaged.  The actual mechanics are a little more complex and careful, but that's the immediate effect.  The choice of training samples is in your input-layer parameters.  What I think you're thinking here is quite correct: you want a good spread of labels in each batch, so you don't start training to a narrow slice of classes early on.  Look for a **random** or **shuffle** keyword.  I'm afraid I don't recall immediately, as I've been working in Caffe for a few months.